# How to define UUID property in JSON Schema and Open API (OAS)

Tags: jsonschema, openapi

When using [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) and [Open API specification (OAS)](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) to document a REST API, how do I define the [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) property?

Comment: Also see: https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/542 and https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/pull/715

Answer (score 148, accepted):

There's no built-in `type` for UUID, but the OpenAPI Specification suggests using

```
type: string
format: uuid
```

From the [Data Types](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.1.md#data-types) section (emphasis mine):

> Primitives have an optional modifier property: `format`. OAS uses several known formats to define in fine detail the data type being used. However, to support documentation needs, the `format` property is an open string-valued property, and can have any value. **Formats such as `"email"`, `"uuid"`, and so on, MAY be used even though undefined by this specification.**

For example, Swagger Codegen maps `format: uuid` to `System.Guid` in C# or `java.util.UUID` in Java. Tools that don't support `format: uuid` will handle it as just `type: string`.

Comment: This is only correct for OpenAPI 3.0, and not correct for OpenAPI 3.1 or above.

Comment: @Relequestual do you mean the fact that since JSON Schema 2019-09 the `format` is an annotation and not an assertion? Or something else?

Comment: Additionally, OpenAPI 3.1 uses JSON Schema fully, while OpenAPI 3.0 uses its own schema format. As of JSON Schema 2020-12 (which is what OAS 3.1 uses), `format` is annotation only, but you can use an assertion version of `format` if you define a JSON Schema dialect using the "format assertion Vocabulary".

Answer (score 47):

The only way I found so far is to manually specify the RegEx pattern as reusable schema component:

```
openapi: 3.0.1

paths:
  /transactions/:
    post:
      responses:
        200:
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  transactionId:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/uuid'

components:
  schemas:
    uuid:
      type: string
      pattern: '^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$'
      # the regex above limits the length;
      # however, some tools might require explicit settings:
      minLength: 36
      maxLength: 36
```

But, I would definitely want to use a more standardized approach.

Comment: Can I suggest adding the string delimiters:

`pattern: '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}`

Comment: The dashes are optional in the uuid spec, so maybe `pattern: '^[0-9a-f]{8}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{4}-?[0-9a-f]{12}$'` and `minlength: 32`.

Comment: This is hint I needed to address a problem  where the openapi tools were validating the UUID format. Our implementation is adding a prefix, e.g., `Gcc55edda-7acd-4128-877d-02b94430896a`. Just using `format: uuid` would fail the tooling where the path parameter used it. I created a "custom UUID" using this answer! Thanks!

Comment: Does pattern make value required (imagine minLength does not present)?

Comment: @Papooch do you have a source for the optionality of the hyphens, please? I couldn't verify that statement, but would be interested in such a more compact rep. The RFC4122 includes the hyphens directly in the ABNF, and the ITU recommendation X667 says the hyphens "shall" be included.

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu It turns out I was mistaken. Seems the spec does not allow omission of the hyphens, *but* most of the systems that consume UUIDs that I've worked with allow it, so it was my assumption. If you are interested in a compact representation of UUID for *your* system, check out https://www.npmjs.com/package/short-uuid

Comment: @Papooch thanks for the quick feedback. In our system we actually use a base 36 representation of half a uuid formatted similar to an ip for all ids that need to be as unique as possible while still being marginally user-friendly - they then look like "13t.zr1.9qf.aa0s" and we call them MagnumIDs. That works fine, but its ultra custom after all, so thanks for the pointer to the short-uuid, I'll check that out.

Comment: @Papooch It seems already minLength 32 resulting from the regex. 
Aha, it's for some strange tool.

Answer (score 31):

Since the question was originally asked the JSON Schema spec has been extended to provide built-in support for specifying and validating that a JSON field of type string is a UUID - specifically that it adheres to the format of a UUID as defined by [RFC4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122), e.g. “f81d4fae-7dec-11d0-a765-00a0c91e6bf6”.

The support was added in JSON Schema spec version 2019-09 (previously known as draft-08). The JSON Schema Validation component spec was extended such that the existing ‘format' keyword that can be specified for schema fields of type string now supports a new built-in format named "uuid".

The example JSON schema below declares a (mandatory) field named "id" of type string that must be formatted as UUID -

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
  "title": "My JSON object schema",
  "description": "Schema for the JSON representation of my JSON object.",

  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "The unique identifier for my object. (A UUID specified by RFC4122).",
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid"
    }
  },
  "required": ["id"]
}
```

Note that at the time of writing, the section of the JSON Schema user guide (["Understanding JSON Schema"](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html)) covering examples of built-in string validation - JSON Schema Reference > Type-specific keywords > string > [Format](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#format) - doesn’t mention UUID supports, as it’s out of date - it currently only describes JSON Schema draft-7.

For the Java developers among you, the RFC4122 format used by JSON schema *is* compatible with the string representation of Java’s UUID class - it’s [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/UUID.html) also mentions RFC 4122.

For more details see -

- The JSON Schema Validator spec section 7.  A Vocabulary for Semantic Content With “format” >  7.3.  Defined Formats > [7.3.5.  Resource Identifiers](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-02#section-7.3.5)  - The official spec.
- This GitHub issue https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/542 (01/2018) requested that support be added. And the enhancement was duly implemented in 03/2019. See pull request https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/pull/715.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, the UUID format was not been implemented in 2019-09. See this example, which successfully validates even though ID is not a UUID - https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/lWxTWkoP

Comment: @DavidGard - your comment is very recent - but appears UUID has now been added?  `{"id": '9151f21f-43ae-43b4-92f3-f4af67cdf544'}` validates... remove anything from that UUID, or replace it with garbage, and it fails validation now.