# Required parameters in query are not marked in UI

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui

I have marked in my yaml file paremeter:

```
     parameters:
     - name: someID
       in: query
       description: The some ID
       required: true
       schema:
        type: uuid
```

In generated java classes field is marked as required which is great, but on Swagger UI unfortunately not. It is problematic, because I would like to inform user before fail request that this file is required.

Comment: 1) Is this `openapi: 3.0.0` or `swagger: "2.0"`? 2) There's no `type: uuid` in OpenAPI/Swagger, did you mean `type: string` + `format: uuid`? 3) [Which version](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) of Swagger UI do you use - 2.x or 3.x? I believe both indicate required parameters by using `*`.

Comment: swagger: 2.0

Where to add * ? On the end of name?

 schema:
            type: string
            format: uuid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenAPI 2.0 (`swagger: '2.0'`), query parameters do not use `schema` and use the `type` keyword directly. Note that [there's no `type: uuid`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50204588/113116), instead you need `type: string` + `format: uuid`:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: someID
    in: query
    description: The some ID
    required: true
    type: string
    format: uuid
```

Swagger UI indicates required parameters by displaying a red `* required` note next to the parameter name:

[image: How required parameter is indicated in Swagger UI]