# How do I format string values in Swashbuckle when the type is "string" but another type (e.g., GUID) is expected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, openapi, swashbuckle

I'm using a fairly standard ASP.NET API MVC template with Swashbuckle, which has been working well to produce Swagger UI documentation.

The API in question already had a few parameters specified as string types rather than a stronger built-in type.

E.g., in a model for `Thing`, a person is identified with

`public string PersonId { get; set; }`

In some cases, the base type works fine. In others I'm able to use an applicable `DataType` annotation to get the example to work well.

In the case of data types that aren't included among the `DataType` enum options, is there a good way to get Swashbuckle to tell Swagger UI to display something like "a6ba7a43-090d-4945-9be0-dc0bb2211dc0" instead of "string" in the "Example Value" for REST resources using `Thing`?

Comment: In OpenAPI, [UUIDs can be defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50204588/113116) as `type: string` + `format: uuid`. See if there's an annotation to specify the `format`.

Comment: Thanks, Helen. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute?view=net-5.0), but it didn't seem to trigger any of the OpenAPI definitions.

Comment: here is a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74864021/1303737