# Include format in swagger generated from C# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui, swagger-codegen, asp.net-core-6.0

I've been given a sample swagger definition and been asked to create a web-api to match.  (I don't have permissions to generate the API from SwaggerHub so that isnt' an option).  I need my Web API to generate Swagger docs as close to the original as possible.

The existing Swagger doc includes schema definitions that include properties like this:

```yaml
titleOrderId    string($uuid)
                id of the title order - not a file number
orderDate       string($date-time)
documentCount   string($int32)
```

In the YAML, I see the following:

[image]

I've created the same objects/properties in c#, but they produce the following Swagger schemas:

```yaml
titleOrderId    string
orderDate       string
documentCount   string
```

**Is there a way to specify `format` and `description` in my c# code so that I can produce the same Swagger output?**

I'm working in ASP.Net Core 6.0

Comment: I have no idea why documentCount is string.  Changing the property types as you suggested did actually help.  However, documentCount shows up as integer($int32) instead of string($int32).  Anyhow, if you post your answer, I'll accept is as the Answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as `string($int32)` in the OpenAPI specification. It should be either `string` if it really is a string(no matter if it's formatted as an int) or it should be `integer($int32)` if it is an integer.

The other two are fixed this way:

```cs
public class OrderItem
{
    public Guid TitleOrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public int DocumentCount { get; set; } // or change to string if it should be a string
}
```

---

*UPDATE*

In order to add a description, you would need to install [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations/) NuGet Package.

Then enable annotations in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
   ...

   c.EnableAnnotations();
});
```

Then you add the description using `SwaggerSchema` attribute. You can also set `DocumentCount` to `string` and add `int32` format param. That would break OpenAPI spec, but would do what you want:

```cs
public class OrderItem
{
    [SwaggerSchema("id of the title order - not a file number")]
    public Guid TitleOrderId { get; set; }

    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema(Format = "int32")]
    public string DocumentCount { get; set; }
}
```

You could also do it like this if you really wanted, but I would recommend to leave the `Guid` and `DateTime` types:

```cs
public class OrderItem
{
    [SwaggerSchema("id of the title order - not a file number", Format = "uuid")]
    public string TitleOrderId { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema(Format = "date-time")]
    public string OrderDate { get; set; }

    [SwaggerSchema(Format = "int32")]
    public string DocumentCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the additional description to display?  I tried adding a summary comment to my properties but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I appreciate all your help.  I have one further question.  I just ran across another schema like this: `startDate   string($date)`.  Using DateTime results in `startDate   string($date-time)`.  Is there a `Date` equivalent in c#?

Comment: @RHarris there is a `DateOnly` class but it will not serialize/deserialize in JSON correctly and it will not provide the correct schema annotations. I would suggest using `DateTime` type and `[SwaggerSchema(Format = "date")]`.