# How to dumps Python object to JSON without "" using json.dumps()?

Tags: python, json, django

I need to request post a 36-digit id with other things to a url.
This code should be sent as json.
But when I try to json.dumps() it, the initial and final quotes are also counted and as you can see I reach 38 characters and get error.

```
merchant_id='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
merchand_id_json = json.dumps(merchant_id)

#check len of merchat id and merchant id in json format
print('len merchant_id befor json is', len(merchant_id))
print('len merchand_id after json is', len(merchand_id_json))

# Set header 
request_header = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content_type': 'application/json',
}

# Send request
res = requests.post(
        url=request_url, 
        data=
        {
            "merchant_id": merchand_id_json,
        }, 
            headers=request_header)

# Check res content in terminal 
print('res =', res) 

# Check res.text in terminal
print('res.text =', res.text)
```

in Terminal:

```
len merchant_id befor json is 36
len merchand_id after json is 38
res =  <Response [200]>
res.text = {"data":[],"errors":{"code":-9,"message":"The input params invalid, validation error.","validations":[{"merchant_id":"The merchant id may not be greater than 36 characters."},{"merchant_id":"string is not a valid uuid."}]}}
```

How can I convert this 36-digit id to json format without increasing the number of characters?

Comment: `json.dump()` requires two arguments, so calling `json.dump(merchant_id)` is an obvious error.  This cannot be your real code.  Please show us the real code.

Comment: @JohnGordon I assume it's a typo considering the title specifically calls out `dumps`

Comment: Strings in Json must have quotes. Is the ID supposed to be a number instead?

Comment: it is json.dumps. edited now

Comment: A string is valid json. Have you tried just passing the string in? `"merchant_id": merchand_id`?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61839372/3220135) seems like the answer. UUID is evidently a native JSON data type not requiring quotes, but python is just treating it as a string

Comment: yes. I just entered the code and quoted to make it json.
@

Comment: Because `data` is a `dict`, `request.post` converted it to a form that included an already-json-encoded string. I think you want to skip doing the json encoding youself, stop using data= and instead add the parameter `json={"merchant_id": merchand_id}`. requests will json encode and add content-type to json.

Comment: If the site really did want a form, it would be `data={"merchant_id": merchant_id}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `json.dumps()` at all.  Requests will convert the outgoing data to json automatically, if you use the `json=` argument instead of `data=`.

```
res = requests.post(
    url=request_url, 
    json={"merchant_id": merchant_id},
    headers=request_header)
```